# How can I write this T-SQL cursor?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have multiple values in one cell in a table which are separated by an space from each other. this is somehow how my table looks like, there is a space in between each string in every cell:

```
column1 | column2
        |
abc fgt | rty lkj
```

I want to create another table based on the first table in which "abc" and "rty" are in one row because they both are located in the first place, "fgt" and "lkj" are in another row for the same relational reason (they are in the 2nd place and so on):

```
column1 | column2
        |
abc     | rty
fgt     | lkj
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there always two strings in one column, or can be more?

Comment: Greetings! @erfanic, I request you to please be more specific while asking the questions, because it helps other users to understand properly and provide you with the exact(appropriate) solution. By the way, welcome to stackoverflow. Happy coding!!!

Comment: You can go through the link below to get instructions on asking questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID('UF_CSVToTable'))
 DROP FUNCTION UF_CSVToTable
GO

CREATE FUNCTION UF_CSVToTable
(
 @psCSString VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS @otTemp TABLE(sID VARCHAR(20),tID VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @sTemp VARCHAR(10)
 DECLARE @tTemp VARCHAR(10)

 WHILE LEN(@psCSString) > 0
 BEGIN
  SET @sTemp = LEFT(@psCSString, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @psCSString) - 1, -1),
                    LEN(@psCSString)))
  SET @psCSString = SUBSTRING(@psCSString,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @psCSString), 0),
                               LEN(@psCSString)) + 1, LEN(@psCSString))
  INSERT INTO @otTemp(sID) VALUES (@sTemp)

  SET @tTemp = LEFT(@psCSString, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @psCSString) - 1, -1),
                    LEN(@psCSString)))
  SET @psCSString = SUBSTRING(@psCSString,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', @psCSString), 0),
                               LEN(@psCSString)) + 1, LEN(@psCSString))
  UPDATE @otTemp SET tID=@tTemp WHERE sID=@sTemp                        
 END

RETURN
END
Go
```

It can be called like this.

```
select * from UF_CSVToTable('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 15 55 59 86')
```

You need to pass your column as input parameter.

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/091ed/1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. the matter is that there may be (and will be) more than 2 strings in each cell, the number of strings are also variable, here I just entered 2 strings for the instance.How can that be done? Also the strings are not known, the only thing for sure is that always the first string in first column is related to the first string in the 2nd column,2nd to 2nd, 3rd to 3rd and so on...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can create UDF for splitting values by specific delimiter (in your case this is SPACE):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (rownumber INT , items nvarchar(4000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice nvarchar(4000) 
    DECLARE @rownumber int = 1     

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(rownumber, Items) values(@rownumber, @slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx) 
        SET @rownumber = @rownumber + 1      
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end  
GO
```

After that, it is enough to write simple `INSERT INTO SELECT...` query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table_2
        ( column1, column2 )
SELECT 
    item1.items ,
    item2.items
FROM dbo.Split((SELECT column1 FROM dbo.Table_1), SPACE(1)) AS item1 
    FULL JOIN dbo.Split((SELECT column2 FROM dbo.Table_1), SPACE(1)) AS item2 
        ON item1.rownumber = item2.rownumber
```

`Table_1` is table where actually values are, `Table_2` is table for final rows.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5a7a/1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. the matter is that there may be (and will be) more than 2 strings in each cell, the number of strings are also variable, here I just entered 2 strings for the instance. How can that be done?

Comment: Just add more strings as you can in column1, or column2 and code will work. In demo, on the left side, insert initially few strings, and code will place them by position in strings. Look at the demo again